# Adding variables to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a empty dictionary

```
d = {}
```

I have these variables:

```
key = "foo"
value = 1
```

I want to add them to dictionary as `key` and `value` variables because they can be change in a for loop. What should be the proper syntax?

Comment: or search *anything*?

Answer (score 14):

This is short answer:

```
d[key] = value

print(d) # d = {"foo" : 1}
```

see this link for more info about Python dictionary:

[tutorialpoint_dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

[Python_data_structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)